# Slow parent rotation issue

Tags: animation, parent

[SlowParent.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLBGw.jpg) (the upload from external links isn't working for me it says "File format unsupported")

## The Method

> I parented the circle to an empty and rotated the empty a complete 360, then I selected the circle, then I ticked the slow parent option in the relation extras tab and set the value to 7.

## The Question

> As you see in the gif image, while rotating the scale of the circle changes, which is surprising since I didn't animate the scale. How do I fix it ?

## The BlendFile:

[image]

> ## Edit:

I tried using Crantisz's solution but unfortunately a whole new problem shows up, the entire circle reverses it's animation at the end if I add a limit scale constraint.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the 'Slow Parent' is causing a change in scale - intuitively that just doesn't make sense. Perhaps it's worth logging it as a bug report.

However, you can achieve the same effect using Drivers, using a Scripted Expression to define the relationship between the two objects.

To set this up, right-click the Rotation field in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) and 'Add Driver'. This should make the field turn purple to indicate the presence of the driver.

Swap to a Graph Editor window and change the mode to 'Drivers'.

Select your driver and you should see a variable ('var'). Add a second variable and set each variable to the relevant property in each object. In my example I have each set to 'rotation_euler[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6LCZ.png)' for each of Cube and Empty.

Set the scripted expression to '(var * 6 + var_001)/7 if frame>1 else var_001'. This expression uses a conditional ('if .... else') to set the property to the value of 'var_001' on frame 1 or to the weighted average of 'var' and 'var_001' for any subsequent frame.

[image: driver]

NOTE : You may need to set the 'Auto Run Python Scripts' in the User Preferences to enable 'Scripted Expressions' in Drivers if not already set.

[image: settings]

This produces the following result :

[image: animated result]

To get the child to follow the parent more or less closely you can adjust the values in the weighted average. For example, '(var + var_001)/2 is an 'unweighted average', '(var * 2 + var_001)/3' is more weighted towards 'var', (var * 3 + var_001)/4' is even more weighted towards 'var'. To generalise, set it to '(var * A + var_001 * B)/(A+B)' and adjust A and B as desired.

Blend file : [image]

Comment: Hmm, seems like a painful solution for a simple problem, but well, as long as it works, thank you. Where exactly do I report the bug ? I have never done it before.

Comment: Yeah - it’s a lot more complicated than just clicking a checkbox - but does provide more control since you can use the same technique for driving other properties. If you go to http://www.blender.org/support you should see a “Report a Bug” link. You’ll need to register a new account before you can raise it as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding limit scale constraint will fix the problem, but not slow parent itself.

[image]

Slow parent is outdated feature, if you want more control, try something near Animation Nodes.

Comment: Add the constraint to the circle or the empty ?

Comment: circle of course. Object name on screenshot

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, I update the question again.

Comment: Oh sorry, so stupid of me, I forgot to set all the values to one. But nevertheless it produces weird artefacts. I'll update the question again

Comment: Hm. Clear scale from empty.

Comment: Still doesn't work.